# How to add virtualization concept in HTML table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using html table with fixed height and its has more number of rows. My problem is, the table takes long time to load because of more number of rows, is there any way to implement virtualization concept in the table?, any help should be appreciated. Thanks.

I need something like [UI virtualization](http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Virtualization-in-Silverlight-4-RC.aspx):

> UI virtualization means that generation of items is deferred until we
>   scroll items into visible zone

Comment: why somebodies votedown for this question? any reason?

Comment: What exactly do you mean? please add details, ideas, code.. something

Comment: i need like this http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Virtualization-in-Silverlight-4-RC.aspx

Comment: I wonder why it was upvoted, you've shown no effort to solve this yourself and there is very little information in your post showing what you have or are trying to do. However, I can suggest a plugin based on your comment: `slickGrid`

Comment: +1 because i am also trouble with there. When you familiar with Silverlight this question should be enough. Never vote down without learn about virtualization concept. This is not a good at and all. Hope, others also got trouble there.

Comment: Here's an example of slickgrid handling 500k rows: http://mleibman.github.com/SlickGrid/examples/example-optimizing-dataview.html

Comment: +1. virtualization concept will improves the performance.

Answer (score 1):

HTML has no support for this but there are many JavaScript frameworks which can do this. The general term for this feature is "grid". Try to google for "html JavaScript framework grid".

If you could give us more details of your needs and constraints (protocol that the table can use to load data, which JavaScript framework you prefer, web browsers that need to be supported, etc), we might be able to narrow the selection.